# Can you set init parameters in the jetty-env.xml for the web app context?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using the maven eclipse plugin for jetty.

Is it possible to set the following init param through the jetty-env.xml using the `<set>` tag?

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

I don't want to create my own web app context(webdefault.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. You can use the `<Call>` tag to invoke the setInitParameter method of the WebAppContext to set init parameters. For this tag you set the `name` attribute to the method you are calling and the first arg is the param name the second arg is the param value.

```
<Call name="setInitParameter">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer</Arg>
    <Arg>false</Arg>
</Call>
```

Comment: Creative solution, using the ServletContext init-param to allow the DefaultServlet init to use.  Smells like a bug though, as that technique is reserved for an XML deployable, and is abusing of the purpose and role of the `jetty-env.xml` (solely for JNDI environment setup).   Don't expect this to work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No, as that's a `init-param` configuration for the `DefaultServlet`, which is defined as a `defaultDescriptor` in the `WebAppContext`.

By the time the `jetty-env.xml` has been loaded and is being processed, the `WebAppContext` instance exists, and the `defaultDescriptor` has already been loaded and initialized.

The only place you can specify that particular `init-param` is in a custom `defaultDescriptor` that you reference in your XML deployable for your webapp.

> Note: `jetty-env.xml` exists to define various JDNI environment bound objects, its not designed for anything else really.

Comment: It is possible using the <Call> tag, see my answer.